# Proxy Server Donn't allow to import Google Maps

Tags: android

I have done all the necessary settings of proxy in my emulator using comand line as well as Graphical from the emulator's mobile settings. By doing this internet browsing is running in my emulator, but when i run my project to import google maps in my application, Only grid shown having no maps on it. I think proxy server donn't let it to download maps from the site. Any kind of help will be appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

You need a Google Maps API Key before you can use Google Maps in your App.

Notice, that you'll need two API keys. One of the keys have to be bound to your debug key (which is used to sign your App), which you use in the emulator and one key for the final release with bound to your retail key (used to sign your retail app)

**edit:** You may want to check out this link [here](http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html)